# I want to make imagefield optional in my form.I tried blank = True But its not working?

Tags: python, django

I want to set imagefield as optional in my form.For that i gave blank = True null = True but it,s not working.There are some question in stack overflow related to my question i tried all their answers but didn't worked ?

```
 models.py
 class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   image = models.ImageField(default='null',upload_to='pics',blank=True)

 view.py
 def register(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = Register(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data['Email']
        User_name=form.cleaned_data['Username']
        Password=form.cleaned_data['Password']
        firstname=form.cleaned_data['Firstname']
        lastname=form.cleaned_data['Lastname']
        user=User.objects.create_user(username=User_name,
                  password=Password,email=email,first_name=firstname,
                                                       last_name=lastname)
        insert = Profile(image = request.FILES('picture', None),user=user)
        return redirect('/')

  forms.py
  class Register(forms.Form):
      picture = forms.ImageField()  #i am posting only imagefield code
```

Comment: Please use `form.save()` instead, do not unwrap the data yourself.

Comment: but how to pass data to create user.In auth_user model user information wil be saved.I have separate model for storing image.For that i need to pass the image data separately how to do that?

Comment: probably the best way to do this is using *two* forms here: a `UserForm`, and a `ProfileForm`, and then you only need to do the "linking" in your view.

Comment: but while creating user i dont want  userform and profileform separately

Comment: try picture = forms.ImageField(required=False ) in your forms.py and image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics',blank=True, null=True) in models.py